# Developing Fibonacci Series in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a code for Fibonacci series in VB, but some of the values in my series are incorrect.  Can somebody help me with the code?

Below is what I have so far.

```
Private Function FibNumber(number As Integer) As Integer

    If (number > 2) Then
        FibNumber = (FibNumber(number - 2) + FibNumber(number - 1))
    Else
        FibNumber = 1
    End If

    End Function

    Private Sub command1_click()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Text1.Text
    Call FibNumber(number)

End Sub
```

Comment: can you provide code examples of your attempt so far?

Comment: compgeek: please Edit your post with some code samples of what's not working. You'll definitely get more help and great answers if you share your code.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I did a quick search and I came up with the following in the first couple of results:

```
Private Function FibNumber(number As Integer) As Integer

If (number > 2) Then
    FibNumber = (FibNumber(number - 2) + FibNumber(number - 1)) 
Else
    FibNumber = 1
End If

End Function
```

Comment: but u need to call the function to print..i guess

Comment: @compgeek That's correct, I didn't assume how you planned to use the Fibonacci series, just how to calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is way old, but I think the issue could be with how compgeek is calling the function.

Instead of:

```
Call FibNumber(number)
```

It should be:

```
Call FibNumber(x)
```

Comment: +1: That's a good spot - its wrong in the original and some of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
Private Function FibNumber(number As Integer) As Integer
    If (number > 2) Then
       FibNumber = (FibNumber(number - 2) + FibNumber(number - 1))
    Else
       FibNumber = 1
    End If
End Function

Private Sub command1_click() 
    Dim x As Integer
    x = Text1.Text 
    Call FibNumber(number) 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a Java function, and believe me; Fibonacci wont get much more faster or complex than
this particular version. It is optimized to operate at about 100 times faster than the original recursive one.

Tip: You might need to change maxN to extend parameter length!
For example if you want to input numbers between 0 and 199, you must increase the maxN to 200

```
static final int maxN = 72;
static long knownF[] = new long[maxN];

static long F(int i) {
  if (knownF[i] != 0) {
    return knownF[i];
  }

  long t = i;

  if (i < 0) {
      return 0;
  }

  if (i > 1) {
      t = F(i - 1) + F(i - 2);
  }

  return knownF[i] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("The Fibonacci Series")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter how many elements-")
    Dim n As Integer = Console.ReadLine
    If (n = 1) Then
        Dim a As Integer = 1
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a)
    Else
        Dim a As Integer = 1
        Dim b As Integer = 2
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", a)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", b)
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        While (i < n - 1)
            Dim c As Integer = a + b
            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", c)
            a = b
            b = c
            i = i + 1
        End While
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

End Module